# Do I need to restart microservices pointing a database (through hostname) after changing IP address behind?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I am working with a team that developed many microservices/apps that point to an SQL server database through a host name, eg. `sqlserver.aws.qc1` (yes, it is hosted in AWS).

The company has decided tochange the IP addresses behind the SQL server databases (including AWS ones).

I know probably this could be a dummy a question, but I was wondering if I would need to restart all the microservices after changing the IP addresses, even when they have some configuration properties pointing to the host name.

Any information or direction about this topic will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally IP clients use a DNS service to translate host names to IP addresses, and they cache the IP addresses for some period of time, called a Time-to-live (TTL) suggested by the DNS server.  SQL Server client libraries don't do anything special here, and behave like any other TCP/IP client.

So after the IP address is changed and the DNS servers are updated to use the new IP addresses, clients will still try to use the old IP addresses for the duration of the TTL.

So yes, if you want to force the microservices to get the new IP addresses you will probably need to restart them.

Modern SQL Server client libraries do have special handling for hostnames that resolve to multiple IP addresses.  Most IP clients connect to the first address returned, and only try the second after 20sec or so.  But SQL Server client libraries attempt to connect to all the IP addresses (either immediately or after a very short timeout for the first) and continue the TCP handshake and login with whichever one is online.  So if you really need to minimize downtime you can add the new IP addresses to DNS *before* the cutover and make sure the old IP addresses are offline after the cutover.  Then the apps should reconnect seamlessly after the change.  This behavior is what makes AlwaysOn Availibility Groups Multi-Subnet failovers work.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I was not very familiar with this process, but the explanation makes totally sense to me and helped me a lot. Much appreciated.